# Creating Composite Custom Control in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a Custom Control in MVC3. For example a control name AddressTextFor, where it should take multiple properties like Street, City, State & Country. With these information I want to be able to call the Custom Control like:

```
@Html.AddressTextFor(m=>new {m.Street,m.City,m.State,m.Country},new {@Id='',@class=''})
```

I tried some code like below but I don't know how to type cast expression value to read above mentioned properties.

```
public static MvcHtmlString AddressTextFor"<"TModel,TProperty">"(this HtmlHelper"<"TModel">" helper,Expression<Func"<"TModel,TProperty">">" expression)
{

}
```

I don't want to user partial views for this.Please help.

Comment: What do you want to do show with the `Html.AddressTextFor`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this, is using **EditorTemplates** and **DisplayTemplates**.

An Editor template, is like a Partial View, strongly typed... where you set you HTML and inputs.

This Editors, should be located in the Views -> Shared -> EditorTemplates folder.
The name of the Editor, should be the name of the type you want to handle, in your case: YourAddress

Then, you use it like this: `@Html.EditorFor(Model.Address)` //being Address of type YourAddress.

You can also use it as: `@Html.EditorFor(Model.Address, "OtherEditorName")` // this allow you to have multiple editors for the same type.

Then, if you want to display the address information... you can use the same logic as for Editors... but putting the view in the DisplayTemplates folder instead.